# Access methods and properties of arbitrary Objective-C object from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webkit

I want to access properties and call methods of an Objective-C object that was returned to JavaScript host as property of exposed object (`[windowScriptObject setValue:self forKey:@"a"]`):

```
- (id) valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString*) key {
  if ( [key isEqualToString:@"b"] ) {
    MyObject* obj = [ [ MyObject alloc ] init ];
    return obj;
  }
  return Nil;
}
```

In Javascript I want to be able to do the following:

```
// a is already exposed Objective-C object
var b = a.b; // reference to myObject
var c = a.b.c; // myObject.c
var d = a.b.d(); // [ myObject d ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`MyObject` needs to implement `+isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:` and/or `+isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:`. By default, Javascript is not allowed to access Objective-C methods; you have to explicitly permit it.

Are you seeing some other symptom beyond that?

For more information, see [Using Objective-C From Javascript](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215).

Comment: i've read all that.
using -valueForUndefinedKey:, setValue:forUndefinedKey:, -invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript:withArguments: one can dispatch arbitrary gets, sets and method calls from JavaScript to Objective-C object, exposed as shown in `Using Objective-C From Javascript`.
I want to go further and return (make accessible via `a.b.c`) another Objective-C object to JavaScript host.

Comment: You will then still need to make sure that MyObject allows Javascript access (which is what +isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript: is for). Also, is this Javascript local to the machine, or coming from the network? Granting remote Javascript unlimited access to the Cocoa process makes the product very hard to secure, and would allow an attacker to run arbitrary code as the user with DNS spoofing (or a variety of other common attacks). This isn't a problem if the Javascript is stored in your own bundle (as in the case of Pandoraboy's Javascript bridge).

Comment: `-isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:` and `-isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:` return NO. JavaScript is local, I want to build more flexible bridge between JS and core app code.

Comment: So what issue are you seeing?

Comment: I'm not certain if this is a bug in the bridge or not. If you turn this into a method call (make it b() and move the code to invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript:withArguments: it works as expected. It also works if you just define a method called -b. It's having trouble only in the KVC routine (valueForUndefinedKey:). I suspect that this routine is not wrapping the result into a WebScriptObject. You may need to open a radar on that (bugreport.apple.com).